# How run sudo -s after ssh login

Tags: bash, shell, sudo, sh

My Step By Step:

1. On myserver.com i paste line "sudo -s" to file "~/.bashrc" in home directory for "mylogin"
2. SSH Login to mylogin@myserver.com
3. After login:

   `root@myserver.com:~$`
4. But, press cntrl+D for exit

   `root@myserver.com:~$ exit`

   `root@myserver.com:~$ exit`

   `...`

   `root@myserver.com:~$`

   5.Do not quit.

Why?

Please, tell me the correct method.

Answer (score 5):

You can store a flag in an environment variable:

```
if [ -z $INITIAL_SUDO ]; then
    exec sudo -s INITIAL_SUDO=1
fi
```

In this case, initial shell invoked by ssh won't have the `INITIAL_SUDO` flag on and it will spawn sudo process. Shell invoked by sudo, on the other hand, will have `INITIAL_SUDO` variable set and won't try to call sudo again.

Note that I call `exec sudo -s` instead of `sudo -s`. Otherwise, you'll have to press ctrl+D twice: first for a root shell and second for an initial shell which invoked sudo in the first place.

Comment: Also note that if sudo -s breaks for any reason, you are locked out of the machine—at least in interactive mode.  If you remember what is going on you can do a non-interactive ssh in to fix things.

Answer (score 4):

The command
`sudo -s`
runs a new shell, which executes your .bashrc.

So what happened here, is that you created a loop where each new shell runs sudo -s, which in turn creates a new shell. At some point, the loop reached the RLIMIT_NPROC limit for the system, and the loop stopped, leaving a huge stack of nested shells. This limit is too high on most system (8192 or unlimited) for you to exit them using your keyboard.